# Windows made 3 primary partitions and blocked me from making more

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I have two OS on my PC - linux and Windows 10 (upgraded from 8.1). MS created 3 primary partitions and the last one was used for linux. I have left some free space to have zone formatted in FAT32 or something to easly share files between those systems and some additional space to have in stock. I tried to format this free space, but I got information that the limit of primary partitions had been reached.

[This is how it looks (some texts are translated).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtdoD.png)

Is it possible to create logical partitions on this space instead of primary? And are those two small NTFS nessesary? I use grub as my boot, will something be wrong if I delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enlarge the Extended Partition. It is currently “full” because of the Linux partitions. After that, you can create additional logical volumes inside the Extended Partition.

And yes, the first partition is necessary. It contains the Windows Boot Manager. Your system won’t break when you delete it. It won’t boot anymore, however, until you install a new copy of the Windows Boot Manager somewhere.

The other partition contains rescue files and should not be necessary. However, because you’d gain only a small amount of space, I’d just leave it.

Comment: yeah, the gains are miniscule

Comment: Enlarging extended partition is impossible, the option is greyed in my disc manager. Can I force it? Is it because I am using this partition at the moment?

Comment: Why use Disk Manager? It’s rather limited. You already gave a Screenshot of GParted. Use that. If you can’t do it from withing your Linux system, use a Live CD/USB.

Answer (score 0):

Logical partitions function the same as primary ones, the main difference is that you can't use them to boot an operating system. So go ahead and use logical drives instead.

The system reserved partition shouldn't be tampered with, in theory you don't always need it. It holds the Boot Manager and Boot Configuration data, and is critical if you use the BitLocker drive encryption.

Unsure what the other NTFS partition is.